# Use provided upload_cert.der to sign a release Android APK file

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, android-app-signing

I've just enrolled in the Google Play App Signing program, which required uploading an encrypted version of the release keystore and had an "optional" step for creating an upload keystore - optional is in quotes, because I think it should be a required step, but anyway, after a successful enrollment, I'm now left with an **Upload certificate**, which I should somehow use to sign my future app releases.

What I've done so far: I created a new keystore from Android Studio, set the store and alias passwords and tried to import the **upload_cert.der** to the existing alias - failed:

```
keytool -importcert -file upload_cert.der -alias upload -keystore upload-keystore.jks
```

> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore
>   don't match

I've also tried to import the upload certificate without specifying an alias (or removing the existing alias and creating a new one), or with a different alias:

```
keytool -importcert -file upload_cert.der -keystore upload-keystore.jks
```

...failed as well: ended up creating a new alias called *mykey*, which wasn't password protected and failed with the message:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key upload from store "/path/to/upload-keystore.jks": trusted certificate entries are not password-protected

...so naturally, I tried to set a password for the alias:

```
keytool -keypasswd -alias upload -keystore upload-keystore.jks
```

which failed as well with the message:

> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias  has no key

...and now I've run out of ideas.

In the meantime, I've sent a question/request to Google Play Support to renew my upload key, but, I'm hoping there is a solution to this situation (the support is kinda slow to reply), since the documentation doesn't imply in any way that generating an upload keystore and uploading the encrypted private key of that key store is a requirement. So, either the documentation is vague/unclear/wrong, or there is a way to use the generated upload_cert.der. Any thoughts?

**Edit:**

Thanks to the answer and comment provided by [Pierre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265103/pierre), I realized that if you do not create/provide an upload key, your existing original signing key should be used, with the **upload_cert.der**. So, the only requirement would be to insert the upload certificate by running:

```
keytool -importcert -file upload_cert.der -keystore original-signing-keystore.jks
```

...and you should be able to continue publishing your applications to the Play Store.

Comment: I have a similar situation where i'm not sure why, but my Upload Certificate had changed its signature when i tried to update to a Internal Track today in Google Play Store. 

I have the original keystore, but the signature for the Upload Certificate was incorrect. I have now updated and got my local upload_cer.der file, but i can only add it as a trustedCertEntry to my keystore. When i attempt to upload to playstore, it says invalid upload signature was used. 

Is this a similar issue, according to your edit - shouldn't this already be accepted as it goes up with my keystore and new .der?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The .der file you uploaded to the Play Console (and that is also available for download in the App Signing page in the Play Console) does not contain the private key, it only contains the public key, so you won't be able to sign anything with it.

Only the keystore you created to generate your upload certificate contains the private key and must be used to sign your APKs (or App Bundles).

In other words, you shouldn't create another keystore after enrollment in Play Signing, you should use the keystore you have created to generate the upload certificate to sign your future artifacts.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, this helps to make things more clear, but unfortunately doesn't solve my issue. The problem is that I didn't create an upload keystore before enrolling, because at the time it was an "optional" step and Google just created the upload certificate themselves, which is not connected to a keystore that I ever owned. Hope this makes my question a bit more clear... I'm trying to figure out why is this allowed if it's not possible to use the auto-generated upload_cert.der

Comment: If you didn't provide an upload certificate to Google Play when entolling, then Play considers your signing key as your upload key, and you should keep uploading APKs/Bundles signed with the same original key. If you want to sign your uploaded artifacts with a different key, then you need to reset it by contacting the support team as you've done.

Comment: If that's the case, great, if I can still use my old signing key, it's an option... Thanks, I'll try it out and accept the answer if it works.