# Sign an Android app bundle with the key from Play Store

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

I'm trying to sign a Android App Bundle and I'm having some problems. This is an old app that have been disabled from the play store, and now I'm trying to restore it. First thing I need to upload the new version to the play store, to which I need to sign the app bundle.

My first try was the `Generate Signed Bundle` option on Android Studio. I've generated a new key, and build the app. But when I tried to upload the generated file into play console, I got the message below (A free translation from the Portuguese message I got):

```
Your Android App Bundle was signed with an incorrect key. Use the right signing key and try again. It should be signed with a certificate with the following digital print:
SHA1: {Big sequence}
. Nonetheless, the certificate used to sign the app bundle uses: 
SHA1: {Another big Sequence}
```

So I concluded there is already a key in play console I Should use to sign the application. When I access the play console, I was able to find some keys, as shown in the picture bellow:

[image]

There is a download certificate button, which will download a .der file, but I don't know how to use this .der file to sign the app bundle. How can I do that?

Comment: You need the private keystore and password. If you lost it, there is no way to update the app.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51107230/use-provided-upload-cert-der-to-sign-a-release-android-apk-file/51112932#51112932